# SSH_AUTH_SOCK held by keyring

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I'm running RHEL with `xfce 4.14`  on one of the work VMs

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.1 (Ootpa)
$ uname -a
Linux foo.local 4.18.0-147.el8.sf02480468.12.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 25 18:17:10 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

At some point I noticed that the keyring seems to "hold" `SSH_AUTHSOCK` and that has an effect of my being able to do anything over `ssh`:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 
/run/user/1932626999/keyring/ssh
$ ls -l /run/user/1932626999/keyring/ssh
srwxr-xr-x. 1 mgajdos domain users 0 Apr  1 15:03 /run/user/1932626999/keyring/ssh
$
```

The way I noticed it is when I tried to push some code to a git remote over ssh, git basically just hung indefinitely. Obviously, the same behavior is also observed when attempting to connect to any remote ssh server.

If I `unset` the environment variable manually everything gets back to normal:

```
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, besides having the `unset` done in my shell profile or how do I get rid of this? I'm pretty puzzled bu this.

UPDATE: so it seems like it's `gnome-keyring` launching `ssh-agent` which then, in turn, holds the `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` preventing any sort of ssh actions unless the said env variable is unset as shown above.

I'm thinking if disabling gnome-keyring might get this back to "normal".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, restarting the `gnome-keyring` does the job. It makes you reauthenticate and suddenly you can use the `ssh` client as normally.

I'm not sure how the `gnome-keyring` locked me out of `ssh` as I could not find anything in the logs, but it did.